# int getting set to null despite being initialized

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have this int I am declaring in my .h file like this:

```
@interface searchResultsViewController : UIViewController {
  int selectedEvent;
}

@property (nonatomic) int selectedEvent;
```

It holds the selected row in a table. When a user taps the row, the int is set here:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedEvent = [indexPath row];
}
```

And then passed onto this method here:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailView"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedEvent);
    }
}
```

However, in that method, the NSLog returns null. I am not editing the int in any other part of the file and I am `@synthesize`ing it at the top of the file. I'm not exactly sure what is going on, could someone please explain?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the format specifier `%d` for `int` type ?

Comment: I should've gone to bed a long time ago... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` is not an object, so you when you use `%@`, the computer looks for something at the memory address of whatever the `int` is set to, and when it finds nothing, returns `null`. To log an `int` use `%d`. Like this:

```
NSLog(@"%d", self.selectedEvent);
```

Other valid types are `%@` for an object (`NSString`, `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, etc.), `%f` for `double`, `%u` for `unsigned int`, etc.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: You're right. I can't believe I didn't see that. I've still got a problem where `self.selectedEvent` is always 0 in the `prepareForSegue` method. However, it's getting set to a different number in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Any idea why? Thanks for the reply by the way!

Comment: Did you put an `NSLog` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to confirm that the value is actually being set?

Comment: I did. If I click on a different row it returns a different number. It's weird!

Comment: What do you mean? Each row returns a different number, but they're never the right number?

Comment: No, each row returns a different number - the row number. The right one. But when the prepareForSegue method is called that number is always 0 - like it's being set somewhere else. This doesn't happen if I use `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. In that case, the value is correct. It seems like `prepareForSegue` gets called first (with selectedEvents value 0) then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` changes it. Then it goes to a different view and when I come back the int is reset.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I've never used the new storyboarding stuff so I'm not too familiar with it.